# In Linked list how to produce value

Tags: oop

I would like to repeatedly enter a number that is added to a linked list.

But there's an error in the code at line `x = new Node()`:

> No enclosing instance of type `Main` is accessible. Must qualify the allocation with an enclosing instance of type `Main` (e.g. `x.new A()` where `x` is an instance of `Main`).

Is there a way to fix my code?

```
    static Node head;
    static Node p;
    static Node q;
    static Node x;
    
    class Node {
        int data;
        Node next;
        public Node link;
        // Constructor to create a new node
        // Next is by default initialized
        // as null
        Node(int d) { 
            data = d; 
            next = null;
        }

        public Node() {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }
    }
```

Comment: Move `Node` outside of `Main`. Or declare it `static class Node`.

Comment: Replace `class Node {` with `static class Node {`. An inner (non-static) class always has an implicit reference on the surrounding object and can therefore not be accessed from a static context. To remove this implicit connection, the inner class must be declared `static`.

Comment: I rolled back your latest edit, because it removes context that is essential to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two issues:

- `class Node` should either be declared as `static`, or be moved to a separate file.
- `p = x` should happen outside the `else` block, since it should get this value also when the `if` condition was true:

  ```
  if(head == null) {
      head = x;
  } else {
      p.link = x;
  }
  p = x;
  ```

### Some remarks:

If you really want to use the `Node` constructor without arguments, then it is better to define explicitly what the new Node's properties should be:

```
public Node() {
    data = 0; 
    next = null;
}
```

However, it would be better to not have this constructor signature at all, and only construct the object using the data as argument:

```
if(num != -999){
    x = new Node(num);
```

...and now you don't need to do any of this any more:

```
x.data = num;
x.link = null;
```

Comment: I have a quick follow up question regard to this.. when I remove this class  `public Node() {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
 }`    it gives me an error of the `x = new Node();` needs a construct .. so my main question here is what input or code should I put INSIDE the `public Node(){}` class?

Comment: See addition to my answer.

Comment: okay, I am getting there now.. but one last question about my  decleared variables  
       `static Node head;
 static Node p;
 static Node q;
 static Node x;`  are these variables correct? by adding static on it?

Comment: Yes, since they occur in `Main`, and it is not the purpose to actually do `new Main()`, they should be static.

Comment: Does all this answer your question?

Comment: thank you sir, one last thing.. Linked list does not mean my inputs will be an array right?

Comment: Correct. A linked list is not an array. It is a collection of `Node` instances, where one references the next. In an array there is no such reference. To visit values in a linked list, you need to always start from the head, and then walk along those references. While with an array you can directly access a value using an index.

Comment: thank you very much sir. appreciate all your answers.. everything is now clear

Answer (score 0):

The inner `Node` class is not static, meaning it belongs to a specific instance of the enclosing `Main` class. Since it doesn't refer to any instance methods this seems like it was not done intentionally. Make the class itself `static` (i.e., `static class Node {`) and you should be fine.

Comment: okay, the error is gone. But after I run the program I can only enter 1 number and the next input is error stating `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException`

Answer (score 0):

First, the class `Node` cannot be referenced from a static context. To fix this, make it `static` or move it to its own file. Second, the null pointer exception happens since you don't assign `p` in the special case where the list is empty.

Overall, I suggest that you clean up your class and use a more structured approach. Rename `p` to `last` to make it clear that this is a reference to the last element of the list. Move the functionality to add a node into its own method to make the code more readable. Use `next` in the `Node` class to point to the next node instead of `link`. Create an instance of the class where your `head` and `last` reference is defined and make them private. Use `break` inside the loop to only define the magic number (-999) once and exit the loop when it is entered.

The whole class could look like this:

```
public class CustomLinkedList {

    private Node head = null;
    private Node last = null;

    static class Node {
        int data;
        Node next = null;
    }

    public void add(int num) {
        Node x = new Node();
        x.data = num;

        if (this.head == null) {
            this.head = x;
        } else {
            this.last.next = x;
        }
        this.last = x;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CustomLinkedList list = new CustomLinkedList();

        int count = 0;
        do {
            try {
                BufferedReader dataIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
                System.out.print("Enter number " + (++count) + ": ");
                String strNum = dataIn.readLine();
                int num = Integer.parseInt(strNum);
                if (num != -999) {
                    list.add(num);
                } else {
                    break; // exit loop
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.print(e.getMessage());
            }

        } while (true);
    }
}
```